# C# EF6.0 Can't reach online database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to publish online my ASP .Net application  but when I try to test my webservice  I have an issue: I can't reach the online database.

When I try from the localhost to reach my local database  I have no problem  It's working.

So I tried to reach the online database from my localhost project and  It keep reach my local database I don't really understand why.

I'm using a sql server database

```
 <add name="InitDb" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-SP8QFTA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ShootChart;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Login;Password=**********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
```

Above the connexion  used to reach my local database.

When  I want to switch I comment the local connexionstring  use the line below

```
<clear/>   <add  name="InitDb" connectionString="Data Source=SQL6001.SmarterASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A25664_Shoot;User Id=DB_A25664_Shoot_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Do you know  how could I make it reach the online database ?

Comment: Is `SQL6001.SmarterASP.NET` hosting your database? Can you ping it? Or is it forwarding the traffic elsewhere? Are you using the right port for SQL Server? This question is too broad; there are too many possibilities.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange  yes  I'm trying to host my .net app  on https://member3-3.smarterasp.net  they gave me several  connexions string like '"Data Source=SQL6001.SmarterASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A25664_Shoot;User Id=DB_A25664_Shoot_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"' or this one '"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQL6001.SmarterASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A25664_Shoot;User Id=DB_A25664_Shoot_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"'  I  Have try to ping  SQL6001.SmarterASP.NET  but  all the packet are lost they use the port 1433

Comment: Then you need to get in touch with _them_ :)

Comment: I have just wrote a ticket to their support  I'm waiting for them now :'( . Thank you for your  help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your 'Context.cs' file and go to constructor method and change it to "public Entities() : base("name=InitDb") { }"

Comment: Hello I tryed your solution, I have  Modified in my webconfig the connexion string   <add  name="DB_A25664_Shoot" connectionString="Data Source=SQL6001.SmarterASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A25664_Shoot;User Id=DB_A25664_Shoot_admin;Password=*******;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

When I call my webservice  It still looking in this data source .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Are you comment out your local string line in webconfig?

Comment: And also it was my mistake. Bring your provider back to 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Comment: My local string line is commented yes

Comment: Go to your 'Context.cs' file and go to constructor method and change it to "public Entities()
            : base("name=InitDb")
        {
        }"

Comment: I changed it like you said  and it's work now ! :) 

Thanks to you. I think it's because since EF5.0 we have to add the "name=database"  because  I just had  name = .